# Firebase In App Messenging Implementation Compiling Errors related to gradling

Tags: android, firebase

I need to implement Firebase In App Messaging

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.3'
```

But it does not let me when add this to my gradle it adds successfully but when I compile or run I get an error CoordinatorLayout$Behavior or Lifecycle error etc

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong, I am new to development and gradle is not my forte

I think it has to do with some internal dependancy how to i fix those, I don't even know how to generate a dependency graph

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }


    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.wavehunt.dilangotaxi"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 7
            versionName "7.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.home_fragment.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            javaCompileOptions {
                annotationProcessorOptions {
                    includeCompileClasspath true
                }
            }
        }
        dexOptions {
            preDexLibraries = false
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
        compileOptions {
            targetCompatibility 1.8
            sourceCompatibility 1.8
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        api 'ru.egslava:MaskedEditText:1.0.5'
        implementation('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.6.2') {
            transitive = true
        }

        implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.6.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'

        implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'
        implementation 'com.github.TheBrownArrow:PermissionManager:1.0.0'
        implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
        implementation 'gun0912.ted:tedbottompicker:1.0.12'
        implementation 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.1.1'
        implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.2.9'
        implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        def room_version = "1.1.1"

        implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
        annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
        // use kapt for Kotlin

        // optional - RxJava support for Room
        implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$room_version"

        // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
        implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:guava:$room_version"

        // Test helpers
        testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$room_version"
        implementation 'com.github.aliumujib:Nibo:2.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
        implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
        annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
        debugImplementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-android-objectbrowser:$objectboxVersion"
    }
    apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my build log

```
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\Dilango\TaxiCustomer_1.7\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, D:\Dilango\TaxiCustomer_1.7\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, D:\Dilango\TaxiCustomer_1.7\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar,  D:\Dilango\TaxiCustomer_1.7\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\590.jar, D:\Dilango\TaxiCustomer_1.7\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\591.jar
    Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
    Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$1
        at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor991.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\Dilango\TaxiCustomer_1.7\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, D:\Dilango\TaxiCustomer_1.7\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, D:\Dilango\TaxiCustomer_1.7\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\591.jar
    Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
    Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$1
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:406)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransform.transform(DexMergerTransform.java:233)
        ... 51 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\Dilango\TaxiCustomer_1.7\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, D:\Dilango\TaxiCustomer_1.7\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, D:\Dilango\TaxiCustomer_1.7\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, D:\Dilango\TaxiCustomer_1.7\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, D:\Dilango\TaxiCustomer_1.7\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\591.jar
    Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
    Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$1
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1431)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
    Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\Dilango\TaxiCustomer_1.7\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, D:\Dilango\TaxiCustomer_1.7\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, 

    Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
    Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$1
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:132)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:117)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:101)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:36)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
        ... 4 more
    Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:65)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:43)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:90)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:115)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$1
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:116)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:74)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:59)
        ... 10 more
```

Comment: Can you post the error logs?

Comment: I added it to the log now

Comment: try deleting `multiDexEnabled true` then Clean and ReBuild

Comment: it did not work, it still gave me the same error